# SCNMaterial: can't find init:mdlMaterial:

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to add a bump map to a material and since apparently there is no way to do it with a plain SCNMaterial, I just tried to use a MDLMaterial instead, and then convert it to a SCNMaterial. There is [a method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterial_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNMaterial/materialWithMDLMaterial:) in the Apple documentation for this:

```
convenience init(MDLMaterial mdlMaterial: MDLMaterial)
```

But I keep getting an error:

> /Users/ramy/Documents/Swift/Space Shooter/Space Shooter/Util.swift:50:26: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'MDLMaterial:', expected 'coder:')

It doesn't seem to find the method. I tried in Objective-C and it still doesn't find it.

**Edit**

I was already importing ModelIO:

```
import ModelIO
```

If I switch to:

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

Nothing changes, I still can't find the method.

Answer (score 3):

you'll need to import the bridging header to see these methods:

```
// Objective-C
#import <SceneKit/ModelIO.h>

// Swift
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

That said you shouldn't have to use Model I/O. Have you tried the `normal` material property on `SCNMaterial`?

Also note that Model I/O was designed as an interexchange format and not all that it can represent is supported by SceneKit. If SceneKit APIs don't expose what you're looking for, there's little to no chance that using an intermediate Model I/O object will help.

Comment: I was already importing ModelIO. I tried to switch to SceneKit.ModelIO but it still doesn't find the method. If I set the bump map to the normal property I get weird results because the bump map is not meant to be used as a normal map.